# R: Cut behaves strangely when converted to numeric

Tags: r, cut

Some example code first:

```
Scores = c(5,4,3,2,1)
Breaks = c(0,0.6,0.8,1,1.2,100)
cut(1.19,breaks=Breaks, labels=Scores)
as.numeric(cut(1.19,breaks=Breaks,labels=Scores)
```

The first Output ist correctly 2, the second is wrong with 4. Why is there this difference? I actually need a numeric value, but the correct one...so how do I convert it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cut` returns a `factor` and 2 is the 4th factor level. You need to convert factors to character first if you want the level labels as numerics:

```
as.numeric(as.character(cut(1.19,breaks=Breaks,labels=Scores)))
[1] 2
```

Comment: I obivously still don't really understand this factor type. But it works like a charm, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the levels of the factor out for each element. Try:

```
f <- cut(1.19,breaks=Breaks,labels=Scores)
as.numeric( levels(f)[f] )
```

(While James' answer works fine too this might help you a bit with understanding the factor)